# Data Base Connection Class with PDO statement

Tags: php, pdo

I've just started to learn OOP PHP and i'm trying create class that will do connection to my data base.

The code:

```
  class DB_CONNECT
    {
    private $host ;
    private $dbName ;
    private $userName ;
    private $password;
    private $db;

    public function __construct($host,$dbName,$userName,$password){

        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;
        $this->userName = $userName;
        $this->password = $password;

        try {

             $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName.';charset=utf8',$this->userName,$this->password);
             $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             return $this->db;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            ECHO $e->getMessage();
        }

    }   

}

 $db = new DB_CONNECT("localhost", "oopcms","viktor","viktor");


 function select($db){

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test`");
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row;
 }

 $x = select($db);
 var_dump($x);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::prepare();
```

What I understand is that the PDO object couldn't be created. Can you give some guidance please?

Comment: It's `echo`, not `ECHO` as far as I know.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia it doesn't matter, function names (and language constructs) are case insenstitive

Comment: You are using `$db->prepare` but the correct code would be `$db->db->prepare`

Comment: The problem is that you try to execute a function within your class, not within the PDO class.

Comment: So many years and I didn't know that, thank you @Pekka웃

Comment: thanks Pekka its work just fine . im trying to create cms with oop  and i think the way to create it will be very hard)))

Comment: @Viktorino that last bit is not working because of `private $db`, if you change it to `public $db` it'd work. However I don't really see the point of the class. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: yes i change it and all work just fine )

Comment: @Viktorino The thing is, the class as it currently stands doesn't make much sense in the OOP world. Why did you create it? What's its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Learning OOP is not the reason for creating *pointless* classes.
Unfortunately, you created one. PDO don't need a class to be built on top of it. Just leave it as is.

So, instead of

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT("localhost", "oopcms","viktor","viktor");
```

make it

```
$db = new PDO("localhost", "oopcms","viktor","viktor");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

that would be way clearer and useful

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, as it's true - at least in the stage the OP's code shows.

Comment: Actually I tried to create some helper classes built on top on PDO, but finally found them all useless. The only possible direction is implementing type-hinted placeholders, like nikic did in his PDO helper. But I already have one with such feature.

Answer (score 0):

who interested here is the solution of this and  **Pekka** and **Your Common Sense** thank you for a tip:)

```
 class Select
{
       private $query;
       private $dbh;
       private $row;

public function __construct(){

    $this->dbh =  new DB_CONNECT("localhost", "oopcms","viktor","viktor");



}


public function select(){

    $this->query = $this->dbh->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test`");
    $this->query->execute();
    $this->row = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $this->row;
  }


}

  $sel = new Select();
   $s = $sel->select();
  var_dump($s);
```

Comment: hardcoding queries in the class is not the way to go.

Comment: mmm.. and how i can put another way db connect inside  both of classes that i creating for insert update delete and create  data?? i cannot understand it sorry.....

Comment: pass PDO object in constructor and then assign to a local variable

Comment: my direction for creating cms is create 1 class db connect, 1 abstract class that returning a result of query and children classes that talks to the data base, and 1 class of validation.

Comment: you don't need connection class, you don't need abstract class that returning a result of query and you don't need children classes that talks to the data base. PDO already can do it all WAY better

Comment: you mean to do this with functions and not classes??? becouse im all ready done one smc with pdo statement and now when i need add some updates of modules or querys  its do a lot of problems

Comment: If you have any problems - ask on these problems. But this class you created makes no sense.